# Any solution for App Store Connect ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage? I tried my best

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic3, cordova-plugins

Even updating the plugins and searching for references from the infamous UIWebView I still get the error.

Config:

- Ionic 3
- Angular 5
- Ionic Angular 3.9.2
- Global Cordova 10.0.0

Config.xml whith:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
    <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
    </feature>
<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
```

Package.json with:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-server": "5.2.11",
    "@fnando/cnpj": "^0.1.1",
    "@fnando/cpf": "^0.1.1",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/clipboard": "^4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/email-composer": "^5.3.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-opener": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/firebase-analytics": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/http": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/onesignal": "^4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/safari-view-controller": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/screen-orientation": "^4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/sqlite": "^4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/toast": "^4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/youtube-video-player": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic/cloud-angular": "^0.12.0",
    "@ionic/lab": "^2.0.6",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.8.11",
    "android-versions": "^1.2.1",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.9.0",
    "angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "brmasker-ionic-3": "^1.6.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.3",
    "chartjs-plugin-annotation": "^0.5.7",
    "clipboard": "^2.0.4",
    "cordova-browser": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-clipboard": "1.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "^2.4.1",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx": "^1.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "^1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "0.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-document-viewer": "~0.9.10",
    "cordova-plugin-email-composer": "0.9.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": "~2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-filepath": "1.5.1",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ios-camera-permissions": "1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": "3.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-x-toast": "2.7.2",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^3.3.0",
    "cordova-support-android-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "cordova-support-google-services": "^1.3.2",
    "countup.js-angular2": "^6.0.2",
    "d3": "^5.7.0",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "firebase": "^3.9.0",
    "highcharts": "^6.1.0",
    "highcharts-rounded-corners": "github:highcharts/rounded-corners#master",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-alpha.12",
    "intersection-observer": "^0.5.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "mydatepicker": "^2.6.3",
    "ng2-cache-service": "^1.1.1",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
    "ngx-d3-liquid-fill-gauge": "^1.0.8",
    "ngx-liquid-gauge": "^2.0.3",
    "ngx-skeleton-loader": "^1.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "onesignal-cordova-plugin": "2.4.6",
    "pdfmake": "^0.1.62",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.11",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^7.33.1",
    "typewriterjs": "^1.0.0",
    "underscore": "^1.9.1",
    "uuid": "^3.2.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.4",
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.13",
    "bluebird": "^3.7.2",
    "chalk": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-android": "^9.0.0",
    "cordova-ios": "^6.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^5.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-safariviewcontroller": "^1.6.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-youtube-video-player": "^2.4.0",
    "jest": "^24.0.0",
    "jest-preset-angular": "^6.0.2",
    "karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
    "query-string": "^6.12.1",
    "tslint-config-airbnb": "^5.11.1",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
```

I've already updated the critical plugins, revised the config.xml and even tried some modified plugins and nothing. The point is that they emit the error but do not even give a hint of what may be causing it, it was very confusing. I've done several searches and tried several possible solutions and nothing ... I've already built an application from scratch with the same critical plugins (cordova-plugin-inappbrowser, cordova-plugin-whitelist, cordova-plugin-x-social-sharing, cordova- plugin-camera, cordova-plugin-safariviewcontroller, cordova-plugin-youtube-video-player) and passed! My application and it has been very difficult to find the point to correct.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Out of Apache-controlled repos, you need to either use:

- `cordova-ios@5.1.1` WITH `<preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />` configuration & a wkwebview plugin.
- `cordova-ios@6` which has all `UIWebView` references physically removed, effectively forcing the `WKWebViewOnly` to true.

If you use `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`, you'll also need to update this to the latest available version.

If you still get the deprecation error from Apple, this means you have a third-party plugin that is referencing `UIWebView`. This could either be in the plugin sources (easily findable via project wide searches) or the plugin could depend on a third-party library that is precompiled (much more difficult to find via textual searches).

From my experience helping others with this same problem, common culprits are:

- google maps plugin (I know they have this patched, so use the latest version)
- Google FCM plugin (not sure if patched)
- Pretty much any social media plugin

In your specific case, `cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing` is the culprit (at least one culprit, you have many plugins, I didn't check them all). It hasn't been updated in years, and in their master branch, it still contains a `UIWebView` reference [here](https://github.com/codeborne/cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing/blob/master/src/ios/SocialSharing.m#L40).

Comment: Thanks Norman, I had already done all the steps mentioned, and in fact the problematic plugin was the onesignal-cordova-plugin, updating this particular plugin ended up solving the problem, since all the other plugins that still used or quoted uiwebview had already been updated.